# AJAX Load Content without Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to load content without refreshing the page. The problem is that I did it but it didn't load the images files and the CSS files.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
            $(function(){
                $('.link').click(function(){
                    var page=$(this).attr('value');
                    console.log(page);

                $('#display').load(page);
                });
            })
      </script>

<select >
         <option value="#">Home</option>
         <option value="../myProjects/Aion-Paradise/index.html" class="link">Aion-Paradise</option>
         <option value="../myProjects/L2illusions/index.html" class="link">L2 Illutions</option>
         <option value="../myProjects/l2sold/index.html" class="link">L2 Sold</option>
         <option value="../myProjects/TemplateID1/index.html" class="link">Template 1</option>
         <option value="../myProjects/TemplateID2/index.html" class="link">Template 2</option>
    </select>

<p><br>
<div id="display"></div>
```

It loads the HTML files but not all the content with images and CSS files. Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the .load() command it is rendering the html from the selected pages. Check the rendered source code and ensure that the css and image links are correct for the page they are being rendered on.

Edit:
Inside your html file you may have an image like so:

```
<img src='../myimage.gif' />
```

This may be fine if you go directly to the html file in your browser, but when the page is rendered inside your div the src might be more like this:

```
<img src'myimage.gif' />
```

This all depends on how you have layed out your folder structure and where your image/css files are in relation to your pages.

Comment: If this answer helped you can you please mark it as answered. If you have solved it in your own way can you update your own answer to say how it was solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the "value" attribute to "href"
 from this code

```js
$(function(){
                $('.link').click(function(){
                    var page=$(this).attr('value');
                    console.log(page);

                $('#display').load(page);
                });
            })
```

to this code

```js
$(function() {
  $('.link').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href'); // 'href' contains your url
    console.log(page);

    $('#display').load(page);
  });
})
```